# Promise error message shown but error is not caught

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise

I'm trying to use helper function exported from `helpers.js` to `signUp` the user and add it to Firebase collection inside React app. Everything works fine with valid data, but when I try to sign up without (or invalid) data, the error is shown but I'm still getting Uncaught in the console.

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BLVj.jpg

Helper function

```
const signUp = async(email, password) => {

    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).set({
            email: res.user.email,
            emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified,
            displayName: res.user.displayName,
            phoneNumber: res.user.phoneNumber,
            photoUrl: res.user.photoURL,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        });
    })
};
```

React component function

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            setLoader(true);
            const {email, password} = e.target.elements;

            signUp(email.value, password.value).then(() => {
                    setLoader(false);
                    history.push('/dashboard');
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                   setError(err.message);
                   setLoader(false);
                });
    };
```

Comment: try by using try/catch inside async function.

Comment: why are you doing `await` and `.then()`? you should do `const res = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` and then do your stuff in the `.then()` callback after

Comment: There's a possibility that somewhere in the firebase code, they mess up on returning a promise and create 2 promises, 1 that they return to you, and leave another one hanging (I've done this before). This would result in uncaught errors but it's not something you'd be able to fix.

Comment: @TkoL Im not sure thats the case, because if replace `handleSubmit` code with `signUp` code  and add catch at the end, im not getting uncaught anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should return promise

```
const signUp =(email, password) => {

    return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).set({
            email: res.user.email,
            emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified,
            displayName: res.user.displayName,
            phoneNumber: res.user.phoneNumber,
            photoUrl: res.user.photoURL,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: Removing `async` completely solved the issue. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @AziralKMG please mark as answer if its helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

convert this

```
await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        return db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).set({
            email: res.user.email,
            emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified,
            displayName: res.user.displayName,
            phoneNumber: res.user.phoneNumber,
            photoUrl: res.user.photoURL,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        });
    })
```

to

```
try {
   let res = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
   const db = firebase.firestore();
   let created = db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).set({
      email: res.user.email,
      emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified,
      displayName: res.user.displayName,
      phoneNumber: res.user.phoneNumber,
      photoUrl: res.user.photoURL,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    });

    if (created)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Now you can find the proper error and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing your catch statement inside the async function  and return the result of your firebase function , it aslo be convenient to handle the errors from tyour firebase action in case anything happend there:

```
const signUp = async(email, password) => {
    try {

    let result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).set({
            email: res.user.email,
            emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified,
            displayName: res.user.displayName,
            phoneNumber: res.user.phoneNumber,
            photoUrl: res.user.photoURL,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        })
        .catch(error){
         return error
       }
    })

   return result

   }
   catch ( error ){
    // Handle your error here
    return error
   }
};
```